# How to represent a PHP array in a ZF2 "twig" view

Tags: php, arrays, twig

In my Service I am executing this query to find out the # of prayer requests in each prayer request category:

```
SELECT a0_.prayer_request_category_reference AS prayer_request_category_reference_0, COUNT(a0_.reference) AS sclr_1 FROM acts2301_prayer.pr a0_ GROUP BY a0_.prayer_request_category_reference
```

Then I assign the results to an array:

```
if (is_array($result) && count($result) > '0') {
    foreach ($result AS $value) {
        $cateogry_request_count[$value['prayerRequestCategoryReference']] = $value['category_request_count'];
    }
}
```

The results of " print_r( $cateogry_request_count ) " are

```
 Array
 {
     [1] => 5
     [2] => 5
     [3] => 5
     [4] => 2
     [5] => 1
     [8] => 3
 )
```

I am unsure of how to represent this array within my Twig view.  I am displaying this within the context of a loop.  This variable in my service " $value['prayerRequestCategoryReference'] " equals " value.reference " in the loop within my Twig.

The following are my unsuccessful attempts to present category_request_count.#

Try #1:

```
 {% set yourNewVarName = category_request_count.value.reference %}
 {{ yourNewVarName|escape }}
```

Try #2:

```
 {{ 'category_request_count' . value.reference }}
```

Try #3:

```
 {{ category_request_count . value.reference }}
```

Comment: Try `{{ category_request_count[value.reference] }}` or `{{ attribute(category_request_count, value.reference) }}`

Comment: Both of your solutions work.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables), to access a "dynamic" attribute of a variable you can do

```
{{ category_request_count[value.reference] }}
```

or using the [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function

```
{{ attribute(category_request_count, value.reference) }}
```